# Sort a part of array from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I need to sort an array based on another array. However, there is a larger array but I only want to sort on some items properties. The first array looks like this :

```
var data = [ { id : "23", name : "Item 1", isActive : true},
  { id : "25", name : "Item 2", isActive : false},
  { id : "26", name : "Item 3", isActive : false},
  { id : "30", name : "Item 4", isActive : true},
  { id : "45", name : "Item 5", isActive : true}
]
```

Then I do this to get the id of active items :

```
var ids = _.filter(c, function(el) {
             return el.isActive === true;
          }).map(function(e) { return e.id;}) //["23","30","45"]
```

I do some operation (database comparaison) and I get for example a result like this :

```
var sorted = ["45","23","30"]
```

As I first sorted items by isActive, I only want to sort items that are active. (depending on the sorted array above ) Like this :

```
var expected = [
  { id : "45", name : "Item 5", isActive : true},
  { id : "23", name : "Item 1", isActive : true},
  { id : "30", name : "Item 4", isActive : true},
  //try to keep order for the last values 
  { id : "25", name : "Item 2", isActive : false},
  { id : "26", name : "Item 3", isActive : false}]
```

I tried to use _.sortBy method but this didn't worked as expected :

```
var sortObj = sorted.reduce(function(acc, value, index) {
  acc[value] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

sortedItems = _.sortBy(data, function(x) {
   return _.indexOf(sortObj, x.id)
});
```

But it didn't work as expected

Any ideas ? Huge thanks in advance =)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what kind of sort you need

Comment: You want first all active item, then inactive but keeping the first order ?

Comment: https://github.com/Teun/thenBy.js

Comment: yes right, the sort is done on active items. But the sorted items are in another array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to keep the order for sorted, and inactive,.
We can use two associated array's to keep an index of the order, you can then use the two associated arrays to create a sort of composite index.

Updated: To hopefully simplify and make easer to follow.

```js
var data = [ { id : "23", name : "Item 1", isActive : true},
  { id : "25", name : "Item 2", isActive : false},
  { id : "26", name : "Item 3", isActive : false},
  { id : "30", name : "Item 4", isActive : true},
  { id : "45", name : "Item 5", isActive : true}
];
var sorted = ["45","23","30"];

//true = active sort,  false = data sort
var order = { true: {}, false: {}};
//create order index for data
data.forEach(function (o, i) { order[false][o.id] = i; });
//create order index for sort
sorted.forEach(function (v, i) { order[true][v] = i });

data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (b.isActive - a.isActive) || 
    order[a.isActive][a.id] - order[b.isActive][b.id];
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 filters and combine the result into one array. 
return el.isActive === true; and  return el.isActive === false;
You can sort both results before inserting into final array

Answer (score 0):

You could use sorting with map and an object for the sort order.

```js
var data = [{ id: "23", name: "Item 1", isActive: true }, { id: "25", name: "Item 2", isActive: false }, { id: "26", name: "Item 3", isActive: false }, { id: "30", name: "Item 4", isActive: true }, { id: "45", name: "Item 5", isActive: true }],
    sorted = ["45", "23", "30"],
    order = {};

sorted.forEach(function (a, i) { order[a] = i + 1; });

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = data.map(function (el, i) {
        return { index: i, active: el.isActive, value: order[el.id] || i };
    });

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.active - a.active || a.value - b.value;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
        return data[el.index];
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account, none active sorting..  although it is showing 25, 26, this is only by accident.

Comment: i do not understand you. what do you need?

Comment: If you look at his requirements he says.. //try to keep order for the last values , your correctly doing the order for the array sorted, but not doing anything to make sure items not in the sorted array are kept in the same order as the original array.  Hope that makes sense.. :)

Comment: @Keith, thank you for clarification. now the no active values stay in original order.

Comment: Nice one Nina, I didn't know about boolean subtraction.  I've updated my response to include it..